# Pandas: If string exists in one of the columns, copy the date to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe that contains all strings:
[Current Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeoCv.png)

I would like to add a Column ("Accepted Date") that captures the date from any comment that contains the words "Now Accepted" like the following:

[Desired Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVk3c.png)

I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser as dparser

df= pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3],'cmnt1':["7/23/2021; bla bla Now Accepted", np.nan, "7/23/2021; updated"],'cmnt2':[np.nan,"7/25/2021; bla bla Now Accepted","7/29/2021; bla bla Now Accepted"]})

df['Accept_Date']=np.nan
for y in ['cmnt1','cmnt2']:
    df['Accept_Date'].update(df[y][df[y].str.contains("Now Accepted", na=False)])
    
df['Accept_Date'].update(df.Accept_Date.apply(lambda x: dparser.parse(x,fuzzy=True).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')))
```

### **Output:**

| col1 | cmnt1 | cmnt2 | Accept_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7/23/2021; bla bla Now Accepted | NaN | 07/23/2021 |
| 2 | NaN | 7/25/2021; bla bla Now Accepted | 07/25/2021 |
| 3 | 7/23/2021; updated | 7/29/2021; bla bla Now Accepted | 07/29/2021 |

Comment: This greatly helped me.  I made one adjustment to make it work for me. I replaced `['cmnt1','cmnt2']` with `data_frame.iloc[:, 0:]`